# Disney Infinity on the Wii

Tags: nintendo-wii, disney-infinity, disney-infinity-2.0

I was considering buying Disney Infinity for my son for Christmas. Now, we have a Wii, and I am not prepared to buy a new console. I don't know anything about Disney Infinity but I understand that there are some limitations on the Wii, for example with Disney Infinity 2.0 (whatever that is). Can somebody explain to me in plain English how Disney Infinity works and what are the limitations on the Wii?

Answer (score 3):

Disney infinity 2.0 is released on the [Wii U](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disney_Infinity:_Marvel_Super_Heroes) (and not on the Wii).

Therefore, you cannot play it on your Wii. You need to buy a Wii U.

Comment: Thanks. What about Disney Infinity itself?

Comment: The old version is on the wii, so that will work. You need the old figures and stuff, though.

Comment: OK, so how does it work? You buy the game, but then you also have to buy some figures, right?

Comment: Best thing to do, would be to read the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disney_Infinity), it should tell you what you need to know.

Comment: @am304 Be aware the Wii version of Disney Infinity is cut down compared to the other (non-mobile) consoles - see the "Alternate versions" section of the wiki article.